# How to change a cell of a UICollectionView when selected?

Tags: animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I would like to change, *with animation*, the "appearance" of a `UICollectionViewCell` when it is selected (to make it bigger with more subviews). So far, I have tried many things but none of them work.

### Do you think it is possible and if yes, how would you do?

Any help on this topic would be much appreciated ;-)

---

I see two possibilities:

- first method: register two kinds of cell and do the change in the method

  `- (void) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

but with this solution, the animation won't be as clean as with the other method.

- second method: keep the same cell but do changes in the layout, etc. Again, in the same method:

code:

```
- (void)   collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
 didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSIndexPath * previousSelectedIndexPath = self.selectedIndexPath ;
    
    UICollectionViewCell * previousSelectedCell ;
    
    if (previousSelectedIndexPath)
    {
        previousSelectedCell = [collectionView.dataSource collectionView:self.collectionView
                                        cellForItemAtIndexPath:previousSelectedIndexPath] ;
    }
    
    UICollectionViewCell * selectedCell =
    [collectionView.dataSource collectionView:self.collectionView
                       cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath] ;
    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                          delay:0
                        options:0
                     animations:^{                         
                         selectedCell.height = 20 ;
                         [self.collectionView layoutIfNeeded] ;
                 //[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
                 //    // what here?
               //} completion:nil] ; <- does not change anything

   //[self.collectionView reloadData] ;  <- does not change anything either
                         
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         //
                     }] ;
    
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath ;
}`
```

PS: if possible, I would like to have control on the duration of the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is the best way but I do this kind of thing by subclassing UICollectionViewCell and overriding

```
-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected
{
    [super setSelected:selected];
    // start your animation and add your subviews here
}
```

Doing it this way, you have to be able to "recover" your selected state when your cell is recycled, so you will need to be able to get back to your selected state from `- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` without using animation